# Build-number doesn't work when running from IDE

Tags: git, maven, intellij-idea, ide, buildnumber-maven-plugin

I'm trying to setup automatic append of git commit hash to maven artifacts.
I managed to get it working flawlessly when building with maven from console but when I run it from IntelliJ IDEA I get artifacts with names like `mainlogic-${buildNumber}`

Is it a matter of IDE configuration or a plugin bug?

Bumping version up to 1.2 doesn't help.

My pom.xml:

`<finalName>${project.artifactId}-${buildNumber}</finalName>`

```
      <plugin> 
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>

            <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>create</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <shortRevisionLength>8</shortRevisionLength>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: What do you mean by adding it to maven-artifact ?

Comment: I mean adding to maven artifact's name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is/was a [short coming](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-101599) of the maven plug-in. It has been fixed in IDEA 13, currently available in [EAP](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+13+EAP).